# How to hold on fetch file upto putfile to be complete?

Tags: apache-nifi

Am using FetchFile processor after PutFile. Since I am using Putfile with 'append' as conflict resolution strategy to merge similar lines to particular file.

By overall, nearly 200 success status sent to fetchfile processor for only 5 completely appended file. This leads to fetch file with deletefile option leads to file not found for remaining 195 success status.

I want to send success only once for particular filename after grouping similar flowfiles. Since mergecontent is not logically works, any other option available to do this option in nifi??

Comment: Why won't MergeContent work?  It sounds like you are trying to aggregate related content into a single flowfile as it was designed for.

Comment: No, mergecontent identifies wrongly for continous flowfiles. For continous flowfiles of the 5 files randomly to mergecontent leads to more success instead of exactly 5.